# Is Spring Data R2DBC conflicts with Reactive Redis

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, r2dbc

I have a big problem, could you help me please

I created Spring Boot (2.2) Webflux project with Spring Data R2DBC (Postgresql). Everything work fine, but when I add Reactive Redis dependency, start Jetty container, it throws Exception like this

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-04-03 19:52:55.444 ERROR 2332 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in vn.com.sky.DataLoader required a bean of type 'vn.com.sky.RoleRepo' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'vn.com.sky.RoleRepo' in your configuration.
```

When I remove Reactive Redis dependency everything work fine again

Or when I change Spring Data R2DBC to Reacitve Mongo it's still works fine.

Is Spring data R2DBC conflicts with Reactive Redis?

Here is the Source code demo

https://github.com/roboticscm/r2dbc-reactive-redis

Comment: The problem fixed by add @Table to each Entity